# How to create a new desktop? C++

Tags: c++, windows

How would I create a new desktop in C++?
I know the CreateDesktop() API but it does not load memus or explorer.exe for the matter.
If not to much trouble would love an example to make a desktop with menus.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Window Stations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682573(VS.85).aspx), this may be what your looking for.

However, this also is different from a [session](http://www.ditii.com/2007/07/24/basics-of-sessions-desktops-and-windows-stations/) (UAC).

The source code for how to programtically do this is included as part of [this](http://jobobjectwrapper.codeplex.com/) project ([JobObjectWrapper](http://jobobjectwrapper.codeplex.com/)).

Hey actually, I'm wrong, JobObjectWrapper only *secure's* that interface, the other answerer here was correct, [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472161/moving-applications-between-desktops-in-windows) had the same [answer](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/), virtuawin is open soure too.

Comment: No I have seen this before but saw no resemblence it made to the new desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [virtuawin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/downloads.php) (Open source)

[image: VirtuaWin]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/img/home/screen_1.jpg))</sub>

> VirtuaWin is a virtual desktop manager
>   for the Windows operating system
>   (Win9x/ME/NT/Win2K/XP/Win2003/Vista).
>   A virtual desktop manager lets you
>   organize applications over several
>   virtual desktops (also called
>   'workspaces'). Virtual desktops are
>   very common in Unix/Linux, and once
>   you get accustomed to using them, they
>   become an essential part of a
>   productive workflow.

Comment: No ive had these before its the code im troubling with.to make it start up explorer.exe and window switching